# loop using CStr to increment row

Tags: excel, vba

I am looping through a file (junk data.xlsx) to capture data for (thisworkbook).  For range C1 it is  a direct reference to the data in the junk data file and works just great by using CStr to increment the row number in the junk data file.  But when I use a formula for the cell contents in the junk data file to strip off the left three characters (=LEFT(C1,3) for range A1 I get a syntax error message.  Something wrong with what I am trying to do?

```
Dim r As Integer 'for row count in junk data file
r = 1
Workbooks("junk data.xlsx").Sheets("sheet1").Activate

'loop through junk data file until an empty row is found
 Do While Cells(r, 1) <> ""
    ThisWorkbook.Activate
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=LEFT('[junk data.xlsx]Sheet1'!R" & CStr(r) &"C1",3)"

    Range("C1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "='[junk data.xlsx]Sheet1'!R" & CStr(r) & "C8"

    Workbooks("junk data.xlsx").Sheets("sheet1").Activate
    r = r + 1
Loop
```

Comment: CStr() is pointless here since if r is an integer then the concatenation operator & will convert r to a string automatically. Whatever problem you are having it has nothing to do with CStr.

Answer (score 0):

```
 &"C1",3)"
```

one quotation mark too many:

```
 &"C1,3)"
```

Comment: Juliusz - that did it!  I can do the rest of the macro now.  I am a newbie and would have never come with that.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I misunderstand what you are trying to do, but Left(s,3) doesn't "strip off the left 3 characters". It does the opposite. It retains those characters and removes everything else. You seem to want Mid():

```
Sub test()
    Dim s As String
    s = "Hello World"
    MsgBox Left(s, 3) 'diplays "Hel"
    MsgBox Mid(s, 4) 'displays "lo world"
End Sub
```